# What's a good synonym for "home improvement"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

The umbrella term, "home improvement," is used to describe a vast range of topics, including plumbing, carpentry, gardening, and electrical work.

Are there any synonyms to "home improvement" that have a similar meaning?

For context, I am looking for a word to describe the activities commonly associated with the term, "home improvement," but does not carry the "home" or "house" label. The reason I say this is because for most projects that fall under "home improvement," there is no inherent quality that indicates that they are necessarily related to improving a home.

In other words, I'm looking for an umbrella term that describes physical tasks that one might assume fall under "the trades" or that are completed by a "contractor."

Comment: It might help to know why the term “home improvement” doesn’t work for you.

Comment: I am just trying to find if it has any synonyms, as I can't think of any.

Comment: I don't think of gardening when I hear home improvement.  And I'm not sure what you mean by gardening.  Do you include things like building a retaining wall?  If so, then I'd say landscaping and home improvement.

Comment: It's not my judgement; I found gardening in the definition of "home improvement." [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/essential-american-english/home-improvement), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_improvement)

Comment: How about ***renovation***? ***Remodeling***?

Comment: As a matter of fact, Gardening is indeed a department of home improvement. A practical example could easily be viewed on NZ's largest home improvement chain https://www.mitre10.co.nz

Comment: is 'construction' too simple? construction supplies ..etc

Comment: "Construction" is a good suggestion. But I'm not sure if "construction" is sufficiently all-encompassing.

Comment: Better living through better living conditions

Comment: Craftsmanship, Blue color work, manual labor.

Answer (score -1):

Beautification of one's living space.

I got this idea because I did an internship at Apple, and everyone was given a little budget for "cubicle beautification."